# how to use Link to with Tabs component React from Antd Design

Tags: reactjs

So I have to use this Tabs component and put "Link to" inside the tabs so when click the tabs it's gonna work like when I usually click Link to button like down bellow

```
<Link to="#">
  <Button type="ghost">
    <Icon type="icon-home" />
  </Button>
</Link>
```

and here The Tabs component I got from Antd Design

```
import { Tabs } from 'antd';

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">Content of Tab Pane 1</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">Content of Tab Pane 2</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">Content of Tab Pane 3</TabPane>
  </Tabs>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

So I wondering How to use the Link To with the Tabs component like this. Any help would be Appreciate.

Comment: What is the reasons that you "have to" do things this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused... the idea behind the antd `Tabs` is to **not** navigate away from the mounted component and instead for it to create a seamless transition to another view. So, why would you want/need to include a `Link`? Doing so would be going against its intended design.

Question aside, you can just utilize the `key` and `callback` function to push to another location.

For example, when the tab is clicked, you can use the `key` as a push location in the `callback` function:

```
class TabContainer extends PureComponent {

  handleTabClick = key => {
    this.props.history.push(`/${key}`)   // < == router router v4
    browserHistory.push(`/${key}`);      // <== react router v3
  }

  render = () => (
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="history" onChange={this.handleTabClick}>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="history">History</TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="math">Math</TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="science">Science</TabPane>
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks,that's what I've been talking about

Comment: I know this answer is a few years old, but to answer your question about why you'd want a link:  With client-side routing, you can place a tab-nav inside the router context but above the route switcher, so tabs can cause routing but the tab component itself doesn't re-mount.  This way you can link directly to a tab.  That's why I'm here at least, and the accepted answer works perfectly for it.

Comment: There are two competing design paradigms here: "Tabs" that are actually links to other pages, but it appears to look like its switching to another view (stackoverflow uses this paradigm within your profile view, where "Profile", "Activity", "Saves", "Settings" are links to other profile pages, but share a similar layout). And the other paradigm is that tabs keep you on the same page/URL and offer the ability to switch to other views on click (this is the purpose of the Ant Design Tab component). Ideally, these paradigms should be separate because their expected outcomes are not the same.

Comment: In other words, the first design pattern is actually just a navigation list and the other design pattern is a virtual slide-show (like an image carousel). If you want a tab that links to a page, then semantically, you want a navbar with links and not a virtual slide-show.

Answer (score 5):

Manipulating browser history instead of using links can be limiting. For instance, you lose the power to open the link in another browser window/tab. Links are also better for accessibility.

Here is how you might implement it using react-router's `Link` component:

```
<Tabs activeKey={activeKey}>
  <TabPane tab={<Link to="/1">Tab 1</Link>} key="1">Content of Tab Pane 1</TabPane>
  <TabPane tab={<Link to="/2">Tab 2</Link>} key="2">Content of Tab Pane 2</TabPane>
  <TabPane tab={<Link to="/3">Tab 3</Link>} key="3">Content of Tab Pane 3</TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

Note: the value of `activeKey` will depend on your router setup, e.g. `match.params.id`.

Comment: This would be the ideal solution for me.